# Passing a new node to a pointer within a structure

Tags: c, iteration, binary-tree, nodes

I'm having these two structures:

```
typedef struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *left, *right;
}NODE;

typedef struct bst {
    NODE *root;
}BST;
```

And these functions:

```
NODE *newNode(int info) {
    NODE *tmp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
    tmp->info = info;
    return tmp;
}
void addTree(BST **bst, int info) {
    if (*bst == NULL) {
        (*bst)->root = newNode(info); // <- Breaks the program
        return;
    }
    else while ((*bst)->root != NULL) {
        if (info < (*bst)->root->info)
            (*bst)->root = (*bst)->root->left;
        if (info >(*bst)->root->info)
            (*bst)->root = (*bst)->root->right;
    }
    (*bst)->root->info = info; // <- Breaks the program
}
```

I can't figure out what have I've done wrong.
I'm calling the function like this in the main function:

```
addTree(&binST, tmp);
```

I've used the debugger and it gives me not a single error or warning.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `->` is also a dereference operator, and you cannot dereference NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (*bst == NULL) {
    (*bst)->root = newNode(info); // <- Breaks the program
```

Excatly problem lies here , as `*bst` is  `NULL` then in next line you *dereference it (as you try to access struct member) which causes **undefined behaviour*** and crash in your case .

You need to allocate  memory to `*bst` before access members of the structure. Like this -

```
if (*bst == NULL) {
    *bst=malloc(sizeof(BST));     //allocate memory first and then access struct members 
    (*bst)->root = newNode(info);
```

**Note** - Remember to `free` allocated memory.

Comment: That was the problem..Many thanks.

P.S. I've allocated the memory in the main function will that work fine?

Comment: @DraganZrilić I guess that would work fine for root but as you use recursion so for other nodes you need to allocated memory in this function else same problem will occur .